# babel-plugin-react-css-modules import is not work in less-loader

Tags: babel-plugin-react-css-modules

i try use `@import` is not working。

```
  // a.less
  .hello{width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;}

  // index.less
  @import './a.less'

  // App.jsx
  import './index.less';
  <div styleName="hello"></div>
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
Module build failed: Error: D:/workspace_js/react-redux-boilerplate/src/App.jsx: Could not resolve the styleName 'hello'.
    at styleNameValue.split.filter.map.styleName (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-css-modules\dist\getClassNam
e.js:83:15)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at exports.default (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-css-modules\dist\getClassName.js:66:6)
    at exports.default (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-css-modules\dist\resolveStringLiteral.js:27:56)
    at PluginPass.JSXElement (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-css-modules\dist\index.js:183:46)
    at newFn (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\visitors.js:276:21)
    at NodePath._call (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:76:18)
    at NodePath.call (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:48:17)
    at NodePath.visit (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:105:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:103:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:190:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\index.js:114:17)
    at NodePath.visit (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\path\context.js:115:19)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:150:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (D:\workspace_js\react-redux-boilerplate\node_modules\babel-traverse\lib\context.js:108:19)
 @ ./src/index.jsx 14:0-24 28:2-30:4 28:29-30:3
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true react-hot-loader/patch webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.jsx
```

this is test demo : `git@github.com:ganxunzou/react-redux-boilerplate.git`

test setp:

- `clone git@github.com:ganxunzou/react-redux-boilerplate.git`
- `git checkout css-module-less-postcss`
- `npm i`
- `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

> try use @import is not working。

Mentioned error can be caused by different factors. Firstly, provided [`webpack.config`](https://github.com/ganxunzou/react-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.dev.js) does not include any loader for `.less` css-files, so ensure to add appropriate loader into config: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader
Secondly, styles can be wrapped in independent namespaces, which is useful to avoid collisions between components - so ensure, that [generated scope](https://github.com/ganxunzou/react-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/.babelrc#L13) is used property